# How does this @2x works for videos?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

We have this @2x stuff on iOS that loads images for retina devices, but what about videos?

Suppose I want to show a video on normal iPad and retina iPad. Do I have to have two videos, one normal and one @2x or just the bigger video?

I suppose the bigger video is enough, but I want to know what you guys think.

thanks.

Comment: Probably this: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139299/how-do-i-make-video-resources-retina-display-compliant > will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't do it automatically like UIImage does. But you can check the screen resolution yourself and then decide which video you will play.

But I would recommend you to just use a video which resolution is high enough to play well at @2x resolution since the resolution will be downsized anyway if it is too large.

Comment: This is what I thought. A bigger video will scale down well to the available size. Thanks.

Comment: Video is different than images simply because video is so much larger. If you include videos in your app resources then you could include a small and a larger one as switch between them in code. Or, you could include just the larger one and scale it down to 1/2 half size before playing, this might be need if older hardware cannot play videos at a larger size. But, only some iOS devices can encode movies, so that approach will have mixed success. You can also just put 2 versions on a server and decide which one to download depending on the device.

Comment: @MoDJ great comment, I agree